# Item not clickable

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, https

So I have a task I have a site and there is a button I need to click and take all the info from the next page that opens. My problem is that I cant access the item(I did some research on what the problem could be and none of the other solutions worked for me(By id,By tag name ecs. , waits all of it )). So I phoned a friend and he told the that the button I was trying to click was not a button actually it was a preloaded function so now the question is how can I access that and moreover open the next page so I can put all the information from it in a dataframe.

no code looking for a theoretical explanation.
Thanks

Comment: you need to investigate the function that is being called by the button and determine how it is triggered. then provide more details so we can help

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What is your actual problem?  Can you not find the html element that you want to click on?  Or after finding it, is it not actually clickable?  If you're getting errors, please post them.  Don't make us guess what the actual problem is.

Comment: Would be nice if you can share the code you are using and the code for the element you are trying to click.

Answer (score 0):

If its not a button i would find it by using xpath. If it is a button.
The problem migth be that the button is inside a iframe. You can switch to the first iframe by driver.switch_to.frame(0). I hope this helped.